# Orientation not smooth for android using dojo in IBMWorklight

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, dojo, ibm-mobilefirst

I am a newbie to IBMWorklight and dojo framework. 
I have developed a hydrid application supporting both orientation mode (Landscape and Portrait) . Currently I have ported the application on samsung galaxy tablet(10 inch) . When I rotate the device , the Orientation change is not smooth , it gives flicker effect . 
 I have also added  `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">` in my AndroidManifest file, but it didn't work . 
Please suggest how to make the Orientation smooth?

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer for sure without knowing the structure and code of your application, but one thing that you can easily try is to set mblHideAddressBar to false in data-dojo-config:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
data-dojo-config="isDebug: false, async: true, parseOnLoad: true, mblHideAddressBar: false"
src="dojo/dojo.js"></script>
```

(in your main HTML file)

It seems this is set to true by default in Worklight applications, but this is useless in Worklight apps and can impact performance on orientation changes.